# Latest Windows 10 broke Nvidia drivers

Tags: windows-10

Windows 10 Home x64

Windows update has installed Security update KB4093112, update KB4134661 and Security Update for Adobe Flash Player. Since the update, when I use my Steam version of Microsoft Flight Simulator or my standalone version of X-Plane I get an error message about d3dll not being found, therefore my graphics card doesn't support DirectDraw 11. DXDIAG states that it supports 11 and 12.

The result is that Flight Sim won't run at all (unable to create main window) whereas X-Plane runs at 4 frames per second.

Both ran very well at 30 frames per second prior to this update.

I tried rolling back (uninstalling) the updates, but this didn't fix the problem.

I also tried downloading the latest version of my NVIDIA graphics card drivers and I've done a clean install (erasing all previous files/settings) but that hasn't solved it. Either way it never did this before the windows update so I don't think the driver itself is the problem.

I ran SFC which completed successfully without finding any problems.

I rolled back to a restore point a few week's before the update but it didn't fix the problems either.

How can I restore the previous functionality of my graphics card?

Comment: We are going to need to know more about your hardware before we can answer your question.

Comment: Verify you have the current Nvidia drivers (398.11) installed.  Be sure you perform a clean installation of the drivers.  Your drivers must be installed in order for Flight Simulator X, which uses DX10, to be able to run.  DX12 is built-into Windows 10, DX10 cannot be installed, you everything (except the Nvidia drivers) required to run Flight Simulator X

Answer (score -1):

you should try downloading the latest Microsoft DirectX version. To check whether you need an update, go thru these steps:

Right-click on Windows key and open Update and Security section.

Click Check for Updates button and wait for the list of updates to be rolled out.

If nothing works, try downloading the DirectX End-User Runtime Web Installer from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35). Now follow the installation setup and run the DirectX End-User Runtime Web Installer once installed.

Hope it works!

Comment: Flight Simulator X is a Direct X 10 game, not a Direct X 9 game, which means installing Direct X 9 isn't going to solve the author's problem.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem. Finally I got an NVidia help desk chat on line.
He walked me through it step by step.

Here is what I had to do, hope it works for you.

1. Download a program named "DDU", you can get it from NVidia's
   support or google it.
2. This is a Zip file (compressed) expand and place it on the desktop
3. Choose OKAY
4. Reboot (if youdon't do this you just wasted your time)
5. Click on the yellow folder on your desktop named "DDU.v17.0.8.5"
6. Click "Display DriverUninstaller.exe)
7. Allow program to make changes, click "YES"
8. Choose "Clean and reboot"
9. Watch where this is being installed
10. After "DDU.v17.0.8.5" is done "Restart"
11. Install "NIMOY VIDEO DRIVER.EXE
12. Follow the directions from there.

This is from the help chat line directly from NVidia

AL

Comment: I've just checked a known good download for DDU (incidentally, it's on version 17.0.8.6 now. NIMOY VIDEO DRIVER.exe isn't present in a download. This step seems wrong. Please clarify this point.

Comment: I downloaded DDU (but not from NVidia) and ran it as described above. Yes, it uninstalled the NVidia drivers. Then the PC rebooted into VGA mode as expected, using the Microsoft basic display driver. There was no other driver included in the download, so the Microsoft update reinstalled the same NVidia driver that I had previously. Perhaps this elusive "NIMOY VIDEO DRIVER.EXE" is only included if DDU is downloaded from the NVidia Support Site? Has anyone else tried this?